# Different ways to generate a big number with some small numbers

Tags: search-algorithms

Imagine we have a set of numbers $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\}$. We want to compute the different ways to make a big number $P$ by those small numbers.

For example, if $P = 5$ and we have $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ we can make $P$ by:

- 1+1+1+1+1 or
- 2+3 or
- 1+4 or ...

Comment: Python-specific questions are off-topic here. You can ask us for algorithms, but will have to turn them into code on your own.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known problem called the subset sum problem. Essentially we are looking for a subset of the elements that sums up to a target value, P. The problem is NP-hard, meaning it does not admit a polynomial time solution unless P = NP.  Here is a [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/) that explains how to solve this problem. There are multiple algorithms for the problem. The recursive one runs at in an exponential time of $O(2^n)$. This problem is mostly associated with a Dynamic Programming solution since its run-time is $O(P\cdot n)$, such a running time is called pseudo polynomial, since it is polynomial in the value of the input instead of its size (which is the log of the value).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this recursively. Let us assume that $x_1 < \cdots < x_m$.

- If $P = 0$, return the empty sequence.
- Otherwise, let $\ell$ be the maximal index such that $P \geq x_\ell$. For $i=1,\ldots,\ell$, run recursively on $P-x_i,\{x_i,\ldots,x_m\}$, and prefix $x_i$ to each such solution.